# Systemverilog Generate mailboxes

Tags: fpga, system-verilog, modelsim

How can i generate many mailboxes, for example with generate  endgenerate 
and the how to i put data to one for them.

I tried doing

```
generate 
for (genvar i=0; i<10; i++) begin
     mailbox test = new();
end
endgenerate
```

and it creates 10 mailboxes
but then i didn't know how to put data to one of them
i would imagine something like

```
test[4].put(input);
```

but it doesnt work

any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you a generate-for loop, you need to name the block, and it is the block name that get expanded into numbered blocks. generate

```
for (genvar I=0; I<10; i++) begin : block_A
     mailbox test;
end : block_a
endgenerate
```

Then you can reference `block_a[0].test`, `block_a[1].test`, .etc.

But you probably do not want to use a `generate` block for this as you will not allowed to use a variable to index into the block since the block is not a regular array.

You can simply declare a regular carry of mailboxes.

```
mailbox #(int) test[10];

initial begin
     foreach(mailbox[ii]) mailbox[ii] = new;
```

I also recommend that you parameterize your mailbox by the type of message you will bet putting into it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for everyone in need:

```
// first make an array of mailboxes
mailbox slave_mailbox [TB_SLAVES];
int out;
initial begin 
    for (int i = 0; i < TB_SLAVES; i++) begin
        // then create the object for every mailbox
        slave_mailbox[i] = new();
    end
    // testing if it works
    slave_mailbox[0].try_put(1);
    slave_mailbox[0].try_get(out);
    $display("got %0d",out);
end
```